# i'm getting index not found exception in elasticsearch(Internal server error 500)

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, microservices, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

```
{
    "timestamp": "",
    "statusCode": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
    "errorCode": "hhg.unknown_failure",
    "causes": [
        "Elasticsearch exception [type=index_not_found_exception, reason=no such index [68464]]"
    ],
    "errors": [
        "ElasticsearchStatusException: Elasticsearch exception [type=index_not_found_exception, reason=no such index [68464]]"
    ],
    "remedies": null
}
```

when i try to upload a data through API i'm getting this error if anyone knows please assist me out

i have changed java version to 8 and already given elasticsearch host name cluster all
so now i need to fix this issue as soon as possible

so anyone knows please help me

Comment: Elasticsearch will automatically create the index if it doesn't exist, so we would need to see the request being made

Comment: what call is failing? How have you defined the entity and the index to use?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [create index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html) before sending data to the elasticsearch.

From exception mesage its looks like your index name is `68464`.

You can use below curl command:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/68464?pretty"
```

**OR**

You can execute below command from Kibana dev tool:

```
PUT 68464
```